# Ipyvuetify multiselect function doesn't work

Tags: jupyter-notebook, vuetify.js, ipywidgets

I just started using Ipyvuetify today and I wanted to build a simple multi-select function. Please find my code below:

```py
import ipyvuetify as v

hospital_select=v.Select(
    prepend_icon='mdi-hospital-box',
    style_='width: 400px',
    v_model='e6',
    items=[
        'Lion Heart Hospital',
        'Kindoya Hospital',
        'Port Loko Government Hospital',
        'Holy Spirit Catholic Hosp'
    ],
    label='Hospital Name',
    multiple=True,
    chips=True
)
```

It should be pretty straight forward, but I can't select any options from the drop-down menu.

[multi-select drop-down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX9cG.png)

PS: single-select works

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of an image. Otherwise it's hard to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

the value `'e6'` is not part of the list provided in the `item` trait which I think leads to a bug. In [@ac24](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8731272/ac24) answer, the `v_model` will be unset and it will not be possible to retreive the list

try this instead :

```py
import ipyvuetify as v

hospital_select=v.Select(
    prepend_icon='mdi-hospital-box',
    style_='width: 400px',
    v_model=None,
    items=[
        'Lion Heart Hospital',
        'Kindoya Hospital',
        'Port Loko Government Hospital',
        'Holy Spirit Catholic Hosp'
    ],
    label='Hospital Name',
    multiple=True,
    chips=True
)
```

and use `hospital_select.v_model` to retrieve the widget value as a list

Answer (score 0):

This works for me if you remove the `v_model='e6'` kwarg, no idea why though.

```
hospital_select=v.Select(
prepend_icon='mdi-hospital-box',
style_='width: 400px',
items=['Lion Heart Hospital','Kindoya Hospital','Port Loko Government Hospital','Holy Spirit Catholic Hosp'],
label='Hospital Name',
multiple=True,
chips=True
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It does work>.I didn't find much information on what v-model actually does. I will dig a bit deeper later on.

Comment: v_model contains the selected value(s). With multi-select it should be a list instead of a string.